# Error in handling Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Code:

```
declare C  cursor for SELECT name 
                        FROM [Trial].[dbo].[student]

declare @name varchar(20)
set @name = ''
open C
  fetch from c into @name 
close C
Select @name
```

Could any one help me solving this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'name'.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'name'. I have got the above error.

Thanks for the responce.

Comment: I believe the error is telling you there is no "name" column in the `[Trial].[dbo].[student]` table

Comment: Yes its not name its SName in the Student table.

Thanku

Comment: In addition, what is the point of this cursor?

Comment: One more small help ? I am failed to move the names into a other table.

Comment: @Pearl: Update your question with more details -- how are you trying to move names, and include the `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables.

Comment: Why i have been voted down?
Could any one Please give me the reason.

Comment: @Pearl - because this is not a well-written or well-thought-out question.  Reading the error message gives you the answer very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Your cursor usage, from the example you give, is simply pulling a (random) row from the `student` table.  This is functionally equivalent to the following:

```
declare @name varchar(20)
select @name = select top 1 SName from Trial.dbo.student
```

If you're using a cursor, the syntax should be something more like this:

```
declare C cursor for select SName from Trial.dbo.student
open C
fetch next from C into @name
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        /* do some work involving @name */
        /* fetch the next row from the cursor */
        fetch next from C into @name
    end
close C
deallocate C
```

You'll need to actually **DO** some work in the loop, of course, unless you were actually trying to simply pull a (random) row from the student table.

Comment: Even if you were trying to select a random record, it's much easier to just SELECT TOP 1 column FROM table ORDER BY NEWID()